# Invariant ring of $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, invariant-theory

By classical results in invariant theory, we know the invariant ring $\mathbb{C}[X_1, X_2, X_3]^{\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{C})}$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}[X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2]$. Here
$\mathbb{C}X_1 \oplus \mathbb{C}X_2 \oplus \mathbb{C}X_3$ is the fundamental representation of $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{C})$.

My question is, what about $\mathbb{Z}[X_1, X_2, X_3]^{\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{Z})}$?

More generally, view $\mathrm{SO}_3$ as an affine group scheme, can we describe the functor
$$R\longmapsto R[X_1, X_2, X_3]^{\mathrm{SO}_3(R)}$$
from the category of commutative rings to itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SO_3(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by

$\left[ \begin{array}{rrr} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right],\left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right],\left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$.

You can conclude that the invariant ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\,x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2\,,\, x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\,,\,x_1^2 x_2^2+x_2^2 x_3^2+x_3^2 x_1^2\,,\,x_1x_2x_3(x_1^2-x_2^2)(x_2^2-x_3^2)(x_3^2-x_1^2)\,]$.

$\\$

How about an arbitrary ring $R$ in general? A fascinating question! If you're interested, maybe consider finite fields? I haven't thought much about this, but good luck!

Comment: Surely your observation that this is a finite group is a key ingredient. But not all the permutation matrices are in the group? The determinant of an odd permutation is $-1$ so such permutation matrices need either one or three negative signs. Don't know right away if/how this affects the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think Jyrki's comment is correct, we should discuss about the discriminant $(X_1-X_2)(X_2-X_3)(X_3-X_1)$.

Comment: sorry, corrected

Comment: @Estwald I, too, was thinking about the discriminant. But it is not an invariant. If you flip the signs of, say, $X_1$ and $X_2$, it changes essentially.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, see the corrected answer by Chris.

Comment: This answer is not complete. I appreciate the correction to the set of generators, but it **necessarily** means that the ring of invariants also changes. Building upon @Estwald's suggestion I think that the polynomial
$$X_1X_2X_3(X_1^2-X_2^2)(X_2^2-X_3^2)(X_3^2-X_1^2)$$
is invariant under $SO_3(\Bbb{Z})$ but isn't symmetric. I started thinking about this while lying sleepless in my bed. I first realized that $xy(x^2-y^2)$ is invariant under $SO_2(\Bbb{Z})$, a cyclic  group generated by $x\mapsto y, y\mapsto -x$. I think this should lead to a fix here as well.